# Hotel Management System - Choice Between ASP.NET Forms, Desktop Based or MVC based System

Tags: asp.net-mvc, winforms, crud

We are developing a Hotel Management System based on .NET Platform. I have already developed a prototype version with Windows Forms. But now we need to take a major decision. Whether to go for ASP.NET Forms, continue with Desktop Based system or MVC based System.

The Hotel Management System has a rich object model. This makes the system a lot flexible but it comes with a cost, There are lot of Create, Update, Details (CRUD) Forms for various entities.

The Advantage with Windows Forms is that I can embed CRUD actions entirely in one form but I loose all the advantages of Web.

If I choose web based platform,  I get all the advantages of web architecture but I need to design lot of web pages.

Another Sub Issue is that if I choose WEB, whether to go for web forms or MVC is another decision to be taken.

I need help in choosing the road ahead.

PS: This is a product not a project. Hence there are no bounds about platform we choose.

Comment: You can look at silverlight with ria services which will give you the best of both worlds? Also, WPF instead of Winforms?

Comment: @TBohnen: I completely forgot about SilverLight with RIA services! That's an excellent suggestion.

Comment: More and more LOS apps are being done in Silverlight.  The bad part is, you could end up making MVVM your religion and lose focus :)

Answer (score 1):

I would go for MVC. It's perfect for building CRUD-intensive applications, and building basic web pages (views) is easy. The only downside is that the default page style is a bit "bland". There are many themes available that you can use to revamp your site design (e.g. [StyleShout](http://www.styleshout.com/)). Also maybe look into jQueryUI's [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller).

The downside of a Win32 application is that you have to worry about distributing the application to your users (and any updates going forward). With web, deployments are much simpler (especially if you're using IIS7).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Everybody for your suggestions. We have decided to go ahead with ASP.NET MVC with Razor Engine.

Comment: Awesome idea!  It will be less rich than Silverlight, but the development time will be lower and it will be functional and rigid.